# Simple usage of pyDes in IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

I wrote the code mentioned in the example section of [this page](http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html) in the shell of IDLE, and it didn't execute and returned "SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement". What is wrong with it?

Comment: Did you install pyDes? Also, you should do it line-by-line if you are trying it in the shell.  You are better off copy/pasting into a file and running it.

Comment: Yes, I have installed pyDes, and ran the test too. The shell puts a red bar beside the first line of the code: "from pyDes import *". I have tried pasting the code into a new file, it didn't run, a box saying "Syntax error" is all what I got.

Answer (score 0):

I have used pyDes some time ago (Python 2.7, Windows XP) and this worked fine for me.

Which Python are you using, and which is your OS?

IMHO, your syntax error is about a few indentation problems ==  missed tabs\spaces.

**Check spaces and tabs in your code, rewrite code manually**

Comment: I am using Python 3.3.2+ on Ubuntu Linux. There are no indention in the code as there is no conditional statements. If I put the code in a file and run it, the "Invalid syntax" appears and a red mark appears on the the " after the first %r.

Comment: I was able to run the code and produce encrypted text by using IDLE 2.7.5+, it didn't work on IDLE 3.3.2+. I got the idea to use this version from your answer, thanks viach.

Answer (score 0):

I used IDLE 2.7.5+ and the code produced encrypted text and ran just fine. IDLE 3.3.2+ does not work with pyDes for some reason, at least on my OS: Ubuntu Linux.